# Cannot get ScrollView to working within SwiftUI using a VStack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Every time I try to add scrollview, or navigational view  to my swiftui code, it causes the app to not load anything from the api. Currently I'm using the OMDB api. Pasted is my movie store and my ContentView. Currently I'm using a custom card view to display the image and the title from the movie store, but after trying to enable scroll view the whole preview of the rendered application goes completely white. And nothing will show up again until I comment out the scroll view. I have tried using a horizontal view and a simple image and text vstack to see if the card view was somehow messing things up with the scroll view.

The tutorial that I have followed for getting this far with some modifications is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NvyAN81YcO0

Currently I'm running Xcode 11.6.

```
import Foundation

struct MovieResponse : Decodable{
    let movies: [Movie]
    
    private enum CodingKeys:String, CodingKey{
        case movies = "Search"
    }
}
struct Movie: Decodable{
    let imdbID :String
    let title: String
    let poster: String
    let type: String
    let year: String
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
        case imdbID
        case title = "Title"
        case poster = "Poster"
        case type = "Type"
        case year = "Year"
    }
}

class MovieStore: ObservableObject{
    @Published var movies: [Movie]? = [Movie]()
    
    func getAll(){
        guard let url = URL(string: "") else{
                fatalError("Invalid url")
        }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else{
                return
            }
            let movieResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(MovieResponse.self, from:data)
            
            
            if let movieResponse = movieResponse {
                DispatchQueue.main.async{
                    self.movies = movieResponse.movies
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct CardView: View {
    
    var image: URLImage
    var type: String
    var title: String
    var year: String
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            image
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
 
            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(type)
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    Text(title)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.black)
                        .foregroundColor(.primary)
                        .lineLimit(3)
                    Text(year)
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                .layoutPriority(100)
 
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .cornerRadius(10)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color(.sRGB, red: 150/255, green: 150/255, blue: 150/255, opacity: 0.1), lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .padding([.top, .horizontal])
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var store: MovieStore
    
    var body: some View {
//        ScrollView{
            HStack{
                ForEach(store.movies ?? [Movie](), id: \.imdbID){ movie in
                    VStack{
//                        URLImage(url: movie.poster)
//                            .frame(width: 100, height: 150)
//                        Text(movie.title)
//                            .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .top)
                        CardView(image: URLImage(url:movie.poster), type: movie.type, title: movie.title, year: movie.year)
                    }
                }
            }
//        }
        
        
        .onAppear(){
            self.store.getAll()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(store: MovieStore())
    }
}
```

Edit:

I was able to generate the app with scrolling with the movies popping up from the api. But only with the list attribute. I noticed that I am getting an error, and am not sure if it affecting the pinging of the api.

[image]

```
2020-08-01 18:28:26.274953-0500 Nyx[19421:1105938] Task <B38BF736-765C-4C69-9ADE-AD889ED7BBE5>.<4> finished with error [-1002] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600003c14000 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=N/A, NSErrorFailingURLKey=N/A, NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL}
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing the view code.

Comment: Just added the screenshot of the view code, thank you

Comment: Please do not post images of code - paste your code directly in the question.

Comment: Try to put your ForEach inside of a List instead of HStack and ScrollView.

Comment: I was able to get the normal VStack and Scrollview working, but nothing shows up until I set the simulator to landscape and then back to normal. No idea why that happens

Comment: Navigational view still doesn't work, but I'm thinking that the problem stems from my usage in     .onAppear{  self.store.getAll()  }. I think its the self.store.getAll() that is causing the problems